# Pod is not found when trying to delete, however, can be patched

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a pod that I can see on GKE. But if I try to delete them, I got the error:

```
kubectl delete pod my-pod --namespace=kube-system --context=cluster-1
```

> Error from server (NotFound): pods "my-pod" not found

However, if I try to patch it, the operation was completed successfully:

```
kubectl patch deployment my-pod --namespace kube-system -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"secrets-update\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}" --context=cluster-1
```

> deployment.apps/my-pod patched

Same namespace, same context, same pod. Why kubectl fails to delete the pod?

Comment: Do you mean kubectl delete deployments my-pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kubectl patch deployment my-pod --namespace kube-system -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"secrets-update\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}" --context=cluster-1
```

You are patching the **deployment** here, not the pod.

Additionally, your **pod** will not be called "my-pod" but would be called the name of your deployment plus a hash (random set of letters and numbers), something like "my-pod-ace3g"

To see the pods in the namespace use

`kubectl get pods -n {namespace}`

Since you've put the deployment in the "kube-system" namespace, you would use

`kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

Side note: Generally don't use the `kube-system` namespace unless your deployment is related to the cluster functionality. There's a namespace called `default` you can use to test things

Comment: If I update the secrets and run kubectl patch deployment my-pod, the pod will reload the config?

Comment: Yes, the patch you're using is a common trick to "rolling restart" pods of a deployment. The patch will cause the pods to terminate and new ones spawn in their place, and during this time, the secrets will be remounted into the pod.